# How to translate "get DATA for DATE + 1" into sql query (optional oracle procedure solution)

Tags: sql, oracle, increment

Helo, I cant seem to find a solution for this problem

I have this query

*(Note: the date and all of the columns use VARCHAR as the data type)*

```
SELECT tableA.CODE,tableA.CREDIT, Q1, Q2, Q3, CountedStock, SystemStock
FROM
    (
    select table1.CODE as CODE, table1.credit as CREDIT, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q1 + Q2 - Q3 CountedStock
    from
       (select stockurp.code as CODE, stockurp.credit, stockurp.quantity as Q1, reportenableurp.qty as Q2
       from stockurp join reportenableurp 
       on stockurp.code = reportenableurp.code and stockurp.credit = reportenableurp.credit 
   //  where stockurp.date = '20151001' and reportenableurp.date = '2015-10-01')   
       table1
       join
       (select accountid, credit, count (recharge.credit) as Q3
       from recharge
       group by accountid, credit) table2
       ON table1.CODE=table2.accountid
       AND table1.credit=table2.credit
    )tableA
JOIN
    (
    select stockurp.code as KODE, stockurp.credit as KREDIT, stockurp.quantity as SystemStock
    from stockurp
 // where stockurp.date = '20151002' )  
    tableB
on CODE=KODE and CREDIT=KREDIT
where CountedStock <> SystemStock
```

The main focus are these lines

```
where stockurp.date = '20151001' and reportenableurp.date = '2015-10-01')
```

and

```
where stockurp.date = '20151002'
```

The point of the whole query is to compare the quantity of the CountedStock and SystemStock. To get the CountedStock, I have to count the stock at N date using queries. After getting the CountedStock, I want to compare it to the SystemStock, which is the stock at N+1 date.

If the CountedStock and SystemStock are not matched, then its a problem, and thats what I want to find, but that has nothing to do with the problem here.

The problem is, **I want to get the result for every date**. The current query only gives result for 1 date and I have to specify it myself (20151001).

The thing that got me stuck is the SystemStock date, because if I want to get the result for every date, then I have to write something like

```
where stockurp.date = stockurp.date+1
```

Which obviously doesnt make sense in sql, I cant seem to translate that algorithm to sql query.

Is it even possible to do that in sql query? I'd be very grateful for your help. Oh and, someone suggested that I should be using Procedures (I am using Toad for Oracle) but I dont know how.

So if you have an idea to make an oracle procedure for this, please do tell. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: *the date columns use VARCHAR as the data type*" - why oh why? ***Never***, ever store dates in a VARCHAR column. Things like `date_column + 1` _do_ make sense for a `DATE` but not for a VARCHAR

Comment: You want every date in a range? Every date which has data? Something else? How sure are you that all the string values actually represent real dates, and are they all in the same format in each column? (Not sure why you'd have two formats in different tables as you seem to have, but that's a minor irritation on top of storing them as strings in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are storing dates as strings (which you should never do; [this is about storing as numbers](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:77598210939534), but the same applies), you need to convert your strings from one format to another for comparison, and in the second case also add a day. That means bouncing the string to an actual date and back to a string; in the first nest join that would look like:

```
reportenableurp.date = to_char(to_date(stockurp.date, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

'date' isn't a valid column name of course, but I've kept the left side of the comparison as a string and converted the right side twice in case the 'date' column is indexed (which would also work better if it was stored as an actual date). You could also convert both sides to dates to compare them.

Pulling the date out of each inner view lets you compare them as a join condition; with minimal changes:

```
SELECT CountedDate, SystemDate, CODE, CREDIT, Q1, Q2, Q3, CountedStock, SystemStock
FROM
    (
    select table1.dat as CountedDate, table1.CODE as CODE, table1.credit as CREDIT, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q1 + Q2 - Q3 CountedStock
    from
       (select stockurp.dat, stockurp.code as CODE, stockurp.credit, stockurp.quantity as Q1, reportenableurp.qty as Q2
       from stockurp join reportenableurp 
       on stockurp.code = reportenableurp.code and stockurp.credit = reportenableurp.credit 
       and reportenableurp.dat = to_char(to_date(stockurp.dat, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
       )   
       table1
       join
       (select accountid, credit, count (recharge.credit) as Q3
       from recharge
       group by accountid, credit) table2
       ON table1.CODE=table2.accountid
       AND table1.credit=table2.credit
    ) tableA
JOIN
    (
    select stockurp.dat as SystemDate, stockurp.code as KODE, stockurp.credit as KREDIT, stockurp.quantity as SystemStock
    from stockurp ) tableB
on CODE=KODE and CREDIT=KREDIT
and SystemDate = to_char(to_date(CountedDate, 'YYYYMMDD') + 1, 'YYYYMMDD')
where CountedStock <> SystemStock;
```

Unless I'm missing something, I'd probably replace the inline views with simpler joins:

```
SELECT stock_1.dat as CountedDate, stock_2.dat as SystemDate, stock_1.code,
  stock_1.credit, stock_1.quantity as Q1, report.qty as Q2, count(recharge.credit) as Q3,
  stock_1.quantity + report.qty - count(recharge.credit) as CountedStock,
  stock_2.quantity as SystemStock
FROM stockurp stock_1
JOIN reportenableurp report
ON report.code = stock_1.code
AND report.credit = stock_1.credit
AND report.dat = to_char(to_date(stock_1.dat, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
JOIN recharge
ON recharge.accountid = stock_1.code
AND recharge.credit = stock_1.credit
JOIN stockurp stock_2
ON stock_2.code = stock_1.code
AND stock_2.credit = stock_1.credit
AND stock_2.dat = to_char(to_date(stock_1.dat, 'YYYYMMDD') + 1, 'YYYYMMDD')
GROUP BY stock_1.dat, stock_2.dat, stock_1.code, stock_1.credit, stock_1.quantity,
  report.qty, stock_2.quantity
HAVING stock_1.quantity + report.qty - count(recharge.credit) <> stock_2.quantity;
```

[Quick SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81467/1).

Of course, this assumes all your 'date' strings can actually be converted successfully to real dates, and you don't have any corrupt data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the respond, amazing solution. But it seems that it gives this error when I try to run it: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string. Is there something wrong with the date? it points to this line: AND stock_2.dat = to_char(to_date(stock_1.dat, 'YYYYMMDD') + 1, 'YYYYMMDD')

Comment: Looks like you have data that doesn't match that YYYYMMDD format, probably that the column allows more than 8 characters and someone has put a longer value in. You'll need to check the raw data in the table to see what is there (e.g. start with looking for `length(dat) > 8` as a crude check).